# How to increase the primary partition size? I want to use dual boot but Windows requires 9 GB space minimum?

Tags: partitioning

How to solve the problem above?

I want to install Windows 7 on my computer but while installing Ubuntu I erased all data and now I don't have NTFS partition to install windows. I have a single sda1 of 490GB extended to 4.1GB of sda2. I have tried GParted and Disks to completely format the hard disk but it is not unmounting.

Please help me to create a NTFS primary partition to install windows. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Coud you please post a screenshot of the GParted screen ?

Comment: You can't use GParted for that in your current session exactly because the partitions are in use like the error message says. You need to do it from a live session. But please, before that, update your question with the request above.

Comment: Please refer this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l7hs.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)  after that [reinstal Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and don't wipe Windows again...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to boot a live session, use the partitioning tool GParted, save the changes and then quit the Ubuntu live session without installing.

By doing so you can format your partitions as you want (be careful not to remove the `sda1` partition but just resize it to make room - unallocated space - for a second partition or more).

Then install Windows on the new unallocated space or create and specify a NTFS during the Windows installation process.

Comment: can i join sd2 annd sd5  for windows 7 require minimum 8 Gb space

Comment: Yes but you can also resize sda1 from 494Go to 394Go so that you get 100Go of free space

Comment: *can i join sd2 annd sd5* NO, you can't. They're one and the same. Not really, because sda2 is just an extended partitions that contains sda5 (swap) only, but that's the idea. The only one you can resize is sda1. Again, from a live session only.